# How to implement "Several users logged in simulaneously" in single page application?

Tags: session, authorization, single-page-application

I need to implement "Several users logged in simulaneously" feature in my single page application (running angularjs).

session, tokens, and userInfo are saved in browser localstorage.

How to implement another user session in another browser tab?

Why i need this? My client wants "sharing link" when user gets sharing link he has access to whole application without a login for restricted period of time. So as a result i got some cases where, admin who shares access to any user, need to check that sharing link, and that means in another tab i need to login as a "sharingMode" user etc.

Not sure how to achieve it better and whether it possible without any strange cases. Most applications i know support one user per device/browser.